# How to get access to resource URL params with ngResource?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-resource

I have an AngularJS service for handling buildings, using ngResource:

```js
angular.module('neighborhoodApp')
  .factory('Building', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/areas/:aid/buildings/:id', {
      'id': '@_id'
    });
  });
```

In one of my view, I list the buildings:

```js
$scope.buildings = Building.query({
  aid: $routeParams.aid
});
```

Note that I am getting the area id from the route, but this information is not stored inside my model.

My issue is that when I display my buildings, I would like to use the area id but I don't have access to it:

```html
<div ng-repeat="building in buildings">
  {{building | json}}
  <!-- 'building' doesn't include the area id
       I can't modify the server response and somehow
       I shouldn't have to, the information is inside the URL of the query()
       Can I get URL params from the resource instance? -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this seems ok ?

**Javascript**

```
//Service
angular.module('neighborhoodApp')
      .factory('Building', function($resource) {
        return {
            query: function(id) {
                aid: id,
                resource: $resource('/areas/:aid/buildings/:id', {
                    'id': id
                });
            }
        }
});

// Invokation
$scope.buildings = Building.query({
  aid: $routeParams.aid
});
```

**HTML**

```
<pre>AREAID: {{ buildings.id }}</pre>
<div ng-repeat="building in buildings.resource">
  {{building | json}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply put the area Id on the scope, eg: `$scope.aid = $routeParams.aid;`, and reference it where ever you want. As you are using the single `aid` for the query, won't it be the same for all buildings?

Comment: Yes you are right, I may try to do something like that.